# list window does not disapper of Obout ComboBox control

Tags: asp.net, ajax, vb.net, obout

I am developing a web application. I used ajax Update panel & under update panel I used  gridview for displaying data. In gridviews edit template I used three Obout ComboBox Control(third party) and bind the data from database.for moving one control to another controls I am using tab key.I used tab key from one combobox its move on second combobox when its move then it is displaying list window of combobox it wont disappear after I go to next control and also when I save the data it well display list of comboxBox.

For example of  marked comboBox  I attached two images
1)”[image: BeforSave.jpg]” when I move one comboBox to another comboBox it is displaying list
2)”[image: afterSave.jpg]” when I save the data it is displaying list window of comboBox.
 But when I remove the update panel it won't display such list after focus is moved.

Note:When I use mouse to move one comboBox to another comboBox, list window of ComboBox wont come on screen.

VS:2010
Code-Behind:VB.net
Obout Suite Version:3.5

Answer (score 0, accepted):

using obout comboBox property openOnfoucs="false" , solved the problem. It does not display list window when focus moved to another control.